# NUnit & Exceptions

Tags: nunit

Is there anyway one can output to the console the message of an exception that may be throw during an NUnit test? Currently I use the `ExpectedExceptionAttribute` but that doesn't output the message itself, only checks it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Do you test if exception is thrown?

Comment: Not sure if it's the same, but I would like to get the Exception message from Nunit and write it to the Console, so that I can see my test log in the Console window, with the exception details in it.

This will save me the chore of having to stitch the trace log together with the exceptions to debug what's gone wrong.

Must be possible, but I can't quite figure out out how to do it.

What I'm currently doing in in a base test class I process the TearDown thing and if the test failed I snapshot the screen. That helps, but writing the message out would be better.

Answer (score 2):

If Method doesn't throw test fails. If it throws it additionally writes exception message to the console.

```
[Test]
public void Method_throws_exception()
{
    var ex = Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(sut.Method);

    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

That assert is only `at tab tab` with http://nuget.org/List/Packages/NUnit.Snippets

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
[Test]
public void SomeTest(){
  try {
         ... stuff ...

       Assert.Fail("ExpectedExceptionType should have been thrown");
  } catch (ExpectedExceptionType ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    // Assert.Stuff about the exception
  }
}
```

However I've just noticed [NUnit 2.6 and it's Exception Assertion helpers](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.6).

Comment: Instead of Assert.IsTrue(false ...) it should be Assert.Fail.